# NSMutableDictionary not accepting certain characters

Tags: objective-c, json

I have this NSMutableDictionary and when I try to run this function to add the data, it crashes returning the JSON if there are characters that aren't letters (EXAMPLE would be if the string is (Hello World) the space between the two words will cause crash) unless I replace them with underscores as seen below. How do I get it to accept any character?

```
NSMutableDictionary * dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:msg];
            // If the dictionary has any of these characters within it, code breaks.
NSString *prodNameWithUnderscores = [name stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"_"];
NSString *prodNameWithUnderscores2 = [prodNameWithUnderscores stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"_"];
NSString *prodNameWithUnderscores3 = [prodNameWithUnderscores2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@"_"];
NSString *prodNameWithUnderscores4 = [prodNameWithUnderscores3 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@"_"];
NSString *prodNameWithUnderscores5 = [prodNameWithUnderscores4 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"~" withString:@"_"];

NSData *data = [name dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
dict = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data options:kNilOptions format:NULL error:NULL];**strong text**
return @{ @"name": dict };
```

Comment: can you output the message which you get with your crash?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I didn't need to do any serialization to do JSON's built in converter. I just passed the normal string.